# Is there a known class of techniques about temporary password inaccessibility?

Tags: passwords

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/619152/how-to-hide-a-code-from-myself-until-a-specified-time) asks if a user of a system can restrict their own access in a time-related way.

I am interested in this for freezing and unfreezing cryptocurrency accounts to enforce spending controls, but I am really interested in learning about it as a general class of problems. I wonder if it hasn’t been studied since the concept hasn’t been identified as useful, as of yet.

Has anyone provided an overview of different techniques for the same outcome? Some possible classifications of approaches are:

- intrinsically impossible by design, vs. possible yet inconvenient (to regain access);
- as well as mathematical / cryptographic vs. situational / contextual (as in, perhaps requiring a certain prime number to unlock, vs.
  anything like just needing to go through the work of retrieving some
  password, wherever it’s being kept).

So, what are the fundamental ways of enabling such a function and are there any already established standard ones?

Thank you